# What can I do if someone is downvoting my answers without explanation?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Getting a downvote now and then isn't a problem, but what if someone is downvoting answers without explanation and it seems it is just for the sake of downvoting? I got three downvotes on answers consecutively within 4 minutes and the answers are of old questions. It isn't enough time to read all the answers. What to do in such a case?

The 3 answers are

- [Copying sections of one picture to another](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29206/optimising-if-statement-and-for-loops/29207#29207)
- [Largest LCM of partitions of a number](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28194/largest-lcm-of-partitions-of-a-number/28196#28196)
- [Optimization of "def do_GET(self)"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28799/how-to-improve-this-python-function/28803#28803)

It happened once before that someone downvoted many answers (not mine) at once. In [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28537/better-code-for-generating-primes/28561#28561) all answers except the highest voted answer were downvoted without any explanation.

Comment: It wasn't detected a serial downvote by the serial downvoting system, currently investigating further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've investigated the downvotes and discussed the problem with mods from other sites.

The downvote activity was deemed suspicious, but not quite actionable. If you continue to have like problems, use the "Contact" link at the bottom of the page to report it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that.

Answer (score 4):

I have actually taken notice of this prior to reading this question (I seem to have somewhat of a photographic memory of some rep counts).

Indeed you're right-- there were no explanations behind the downvotes.  Obviously you cannot tell who it was, plus it may be more than one person.  But, you can at least wait and see if this continues in similar circumstances.  If it does, you may *possibly* have a serial downvoter on your hands.

As far as what you should do at that point, I think you would just need to contact a moderator.  If they agree that this is a problem, then they can get the system to reverse the loss.

Comment: Yeah, I think SE can remove serial downvoting if it detects it. But I have no idea how that detection works (it's probably not public).

Comment: I'm sure it's not, which is especially why a moderator must be informed so that the investigation can take place.  In the meantime, I'm going to see if there's any info on this on Meta Stack Overflow.